# Running error using javafx ports

Tags: javafx, javafxports

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':androidInstall'.

  > com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No connected devices!
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: Could you be more specific on your setup? Maybe you could post the build.gradle file if you think it's relevant. Have you already installed any other application on your mobile using JavaFXPorts? You may need some driver to enable the process

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem yesterday. 
I solved it with **download & installing manually the driver** from the internet for my device.
Whats your device?

For Example: 
My device is the MOTO G with Android 5.0.2 
I just searching for the driver in google, installed it by the provider of my phone (Motorola) and tried the command line (`gradlew installDebug`) again.

worked for me. Hope it helps.